# Help me to go GUI of ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

When I entered username and password and pressed enter,it takes me to a terminal saying...

```
Welcome to ubuntu 12.04 LTS(GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23...)

674 packages updated.
267 updates are security updates.

username@Ubuntu:~$
```

I don't know how to enter to desktop.Can you please help me in telling the commands which i have to type to enter its GUI.

Comment: Try `startx`, this takes you to X Session

Comment: If you are in tty then press "Ctrl+Alt+F7" to return to GUI.

Comment: I am afraid you installed Ubuntu Server, not Ubuntu Desktop. If it is the case, just install **ubuntu-desktop** package. CMIIW.

Comment: @Pandyas Comment: run at first  $ who  to see on which tty you are, if it's tty7 you can't use  "Ctrl+Alt+F7"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first run

```
$ sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get upgrade
```

this might take a few minutes(or hours).
If that's finished run

```
$ startx
```

your system is massivly outdated!
This can bring you in deep Trouble.

If `startx` isn't working try,run  like  Ade Malsasa Akbar said

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If that isn't working too( because ubuntu-dektop is already installed) run

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```